# Variable declaration with underscore

Tags: swift, variables, declaration

I have seen this in some videos on Youtube.

```
class Student {

    private var _name: String!
    private var _studentID: Int!

    var name: String {
        return _name
    }

    var studentID:Int {
        return _studentID
    }

    init(name: String, studentID: Int) {
        self._name = name
        self._studentID = studentID
    }
}
```

Any reason why they are doing this (adding `_name` and `_studentID`) instead of:

```
class Student {

    private var name: String!
    private var studentID: Int!

    init(name: String, studentID: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.studentID = studentID
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: rmaddy's answer below is correct. But these patterns should only be used when you really need it to be publicly read-only but privately mutable. But you don't appear to be mutating it at all, which begs the question of why you don't use constants (using `let`) to start with, e.g. `class Student { let name: String; let studentID: Int ... }`. Or, at the very least, why you're using implicitly optionals. And why not use value type? I agree w rmaddy's conclusion that you shouldn't be using those particular videos, as it seems like you'll only pick up bad habits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first examples are essentially creating properties that are publicly readable but privately writable.

The second set of code does not do the same thing as the first set.

The proper way to write this code is:

```
private (set) var name: String // no need for the !
private (set) var studentID: Int // no need for the !

init(name: String, studentID: Int) {
    self.name = name
    self.studentID = studentID
}
```

This makes the properties readable by outside users but only settable by the class. This is what the 1st set of code implements but in a much more verbose and needless manner.

The use of underscore is just a naming convention carried over from Objective-C when creating private instance variables.

Personally, I'd avoid videos and tutorials that use the 1st set of code.

Comment: why would you avoid tutorials using the 1st set of code?

Comment: Because it's not really the best way to write something as simple as a property. And if the author can't do something this simple as well as it should be done, I wouldn't trust other code they have written. But that's me. I want to learn best practices for a given language. That 1st set of code looks like a conversion of old Objective-C code with no attempt to write it properly in Swift.

Comment: @Frankie - The use of tortured patterns and the use of underscores and implicitly unwrapped optionals all suggest an author who isn't a strong Swift programmer. You don't want to pick up these habits yourself. And who knows what other bad practices they employ later in the videos...

Comment: thank you very much. I will definitely keep that in mind when watching tutorials on the Internet.

Comment: @Frankie I can almost guarantee you (perhaps you can look into this), that the author of the video had a Java program, where they were constantly writing getters/setters (unnecessary in Swift, since properties auto synthesize them) and are used to everything being nullable.

Comment: @rmaddy since you are mentioning about best practice, would you mind recommending me any source or reading material so I can learn the best practice in Swift language?

Comment: @Frankie Start with [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) book. That's all I used (and lots of SO questions and answers from trusted users).

Comment: @Frankie - Take a look at Apple's own [Swift - Resources](https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/) page, in which they recommend books and videos.